# Сервер отправляет ошибку 500. Как это можно исправить?

Tags: json, asp.net, xamarin, http-status-code-500

Передаю данные с клиента (xamarin.android) на сервер ASP.NET WEB FORMS. Но сервер возвращает ошибку 500. Пробовал передавать просто строку и все работает. Может я как-то не так дату передаю?

Вот что передаю:

```
 var user = new UserJson {

            Name = NameUser.Text,
            Email = Email.Text,
            BirtDay = DateTime.Now,
            TimeFrom = DateTime.Now,
            TimeTo = DateTime.Now,
            Device = "мой девайс",
            Region = Region.Text,
            Token = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token,
            TimeRegister = DateTime.Today,
            TimeUpdate = DateTime.Today
        };
```

Вот как принимаю и записываю в БД:

```
 public void Post([FromBody]UserJson value)
    {
        UserTableAdapter adapter = new UserTableAdapter();


            adapter.Insert(value.Name,
                value.Email,
                value.BirtDay,
                TimeSpan.Parse(value.TimeFrom.ToString()),
                TimeSpan.Parse(value.TimeTo.ToString()),
                value.Device.ToString(),
                value.Region.ToString(),
                value.Token.ToString(),
                TimeSpan.Parse(value.TimeRegister.ToString()),
                TimeSpan.Parse(value.TimeUpdate.ToString()));
    }
```

Вот сам класс UserJason:

```
    public class UserJson
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirtDay { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeTo { get; set; }
        public string Device { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public string Token { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeRegister { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeUpdate { get; set; }
    }
```

В чем может быть проблема? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Object в Json ? - как минимум странно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TimeSpan вы ожидаете в БД и получаете его из конвертированного DateTime.
Это возможная проблема. Чтобы точно знать, что не так - запустите сервер в режиме отладки и смотрите что получаете.

Можете увидеть ошибку - оберните выражения в [try-catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0yd65esw(v=vs.120).aspx). 
Ошибки всегда собирайте в лог (можете когда нет возможности работать в режиме отладки на сервере), можете использовать HttpRespone и в Context отправьте текст ошибки.

плюс совет. Отделите конвертацию, преобразования и работу с базой в 3 разных метода.